# Partial branch or partial merge or other way to help me to sync dotfiles?

Tags: git, shell, mercurial, dotfiles

I don't know how to make my requirement short in title, sorry if it is not meaningful. I will explain here:

Many people put their dotfiles on bitbucket or github, to ease later installation or configuration, sync over different pc. I did the same, however I want to do something special, I am not sure how mecurial/git could help.

**What I have:**

I have 3 machines, say Home, Office and Client, all linux OS (could be different distributions). To make the example simple, say I just want to put one file the `.zshrc` into repo. The problem is, the three OS have different system variables(or other settings). e.g.

- Office has JBOSS installed, then in `.zshrc` I need export JBOSS_HOME var.
- Client has Oracle installed, then export different set of vars.
- Office has to export HTTP_PROXY, but HOME not, Client needs it too, but different proxy value etc.

Now what I did is, I extract those machine specific settings (mostly export, alias statement) to another file, say `myVar.sh`. and source it at the end of the `.zshrc`.

So 3 machines have common part (same `.zshrc`), and different parts (`myVar.sh`).

**What I want:**

- on any machine, if I found some nice settings, I change the `.zshrc` file (common part) and push. The changes should be easily sync to other machines (by pull, for example)
- if I changed the `myVar.sh` (different part) on HOME, and push, it should not affect Office's `myVar.sh` if I do pull on Office machine.

**What I am doing:**

now I have one Repo on bitBucket, and three branches (H,O,C). On Home PC, I just play with Home branch. Same for Office, Client.

The problem is, if I changed the common part on one pc, the change is in its own branch, a little bit difficult to sync to the other two. Because I would never merge those branches.

I also think about to mk different directories for different pc. e.g.

```
/.zshrc
|--/HOME/myVar.sh
|--/Office/myVar.sh
|--/Client/myVar.sh
```

and write shell script, e.g. check $HOST to decide writing `myVar.sh` to which directory. but I doubt that if it is the best way to achieve my goal. And when I look my dotfiles dir, I see all 3 pcs' setting. I should be careful and enter the correct one to read the file.

In real world, the common part contains much more than .zhsrc (tmux,vimrc,xdefault..), so does the different part.

I don't know can we somehow make a partial branch or do a partial merge on a repository...

**I use hg much more than git, if hg can solve it I would prefer hg, if not, git is also acceptable. I don't have much git experience except for clone, push, pull, up, merge,ci.**

now, **how should I do**?

and, thank you for reading this...

---

**EDIT** more about the different part

I would thank you all guys for giving me answers. As I said above, the different part in my real machines is not as simple as `myVar.sh`. For example, I take my company-laptop (Office) to different clients (There are about 6 clients, not all clients provide us PCs, it is good because I could work with Linux everywhere), and configured printers for each by cups. I would put those configurations in Repo too. Because if one day I have to refresh my system, or harddisk failed, I could setup those printers very easy. Other things that belongs to different part but I cannot simply "source xxx" like

- Xorg.conf for trackpoint
- .hgrc file (since in company we have our own repo, uid, pwd, proxy..)
- some pre-configured systemd modules, basically .conf files. But machine specific, e.g. radeon.conf only for my Home laptop. And Client pc has no systemd installed at all.

  That's why I thought about different directory for PCs.

As I said right now I am with 3 branches way, and have a `myConf` directory, within this directory I have `getConf.sh`, to copy dotfiles, different confs etc to `myConf`. In fact the `getConf.sh` belongs to different part too, because the script is not same for all pcs.

Therefore I think the `if-else/switch` then `source` may not work in this case.

Yesterday I just took the .zshrc, and try to make the example simple. If it mislead you guys, sorry about that.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea would be to write a single `.zshrc` and get rid of the auxilary file. Put various things in appropriate `if` statements to e.g. only set Oracle related variables if Oracle is installed. That way you utilize one common file everywhere - a little more work up front to get it written right, but you don't need to mess around with different branches and forgetting to update one or the other...

Comment: @twalberg I think if "if/switch" should check HOST, not the software installed. because e.g. http_proxy variable, both Office Pc and Client Pc have it, but different values. Also two JAVA_HOME from diff pcs could be different as well. anyway I added an EDIT in question, the different part is not just as simple as `source ...` thanks for the comment.

Comment: Checking HOST is fine as well, although it complicates adding/removing systems from your pool of resources, so I tend to check for features of the host rather than just relying on the hostname/address/whatever. There's a lot of flexibility, so you can decide where on the spectrum between "most portable" and "easiest to implement" you want to live... Trying to maintain multiple different branches/files/etc. can be made to work, but simplifying as much as possible/reasonable is usually the better plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My preferred way to do this is to have a host-specific version for each file all in the same directory -- similar to your same file multiple directories, and then include it via variable interpolation in my main file.  So `~/.bashrc` has inside of this this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc-$HOSTNAME ] ; then
     source ~/.bashrc-$HOSTNAME
fi
```

Presumably that's even prettier in zsh, but the idea is if a host-specific file exists source it at the end, and of course anything that applies on all machines goes in the main ~/.bashrc itself.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added an EDIT in question about the different part. It is not just as simple as `source ...`.

Comment: no worries.  You could still have the .bashrc-$HOSTNAME setup symlinks for the directories / other files, but that's getting more brittle

Comment: finally I would go with shell script + single branch . But I would create different directories for host, and shell script copies files into the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage each setting in it's own branch as you are doing. You can add a submodule (a repo within a repo) that tracks the common files across each. To sync them up, you can

```
git checkout otherbranch -- path/to/common/script && git submodule update
```

To get setup, do this:

in your home directory add a .gitignore file. Ignore everything with *. After that entry, exclude the dot files you want to keep with !.ssh/ for example.

now making this into a repo is easy.

```
git init repostart
mv repostart/.git .
rm -rf repostart
git add .gitignore .ssh
git commit -m "initial start of syncing my settings"
```

This will now track every change in .ssh/. In your case, you can exclude .bashrc and .bash_profile if you like or any other path.

Now you can just follow standard procedure of pushing and pulling from say github or bitbucket (for free private repos).

```
git remote add origin <url to bitbucket repo>
git push -u origin master
```

now you have the settings up on the server. On you other machine:

```
cd ~
git clone <path to your settings> settings
mv settings/.git . 
rm -rf settings
git pull origin master -t
```

The -t and -u options set up tracking so you can just

```
git push
git pull
```

when you need to get or save setting to/from the bitbucket server.

Now to get your common part of the repo in sync, you can read this short chapter on submodules in progit.org/book. see chapter 6 section 6.

Comment: thanks for the git solution. I would wait a while to see if there was solutions other than git. If hg cannot do it. I would try yours. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to do it with Hg. But I know Git better :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by branching in the corresponding files.

Here's a small example showing how I exported different `PATH` values for my Mac and my other computers (inside `.bashrc`):

```
MAC=0
if [ -x "/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder" ]; then
  MAC=1
fi

if [ $MAC -eq 1 ]; then
  export PATH=~/bin/:/sw/bin:$PATH
else
  export PATH=~/bin/:/sbin/:$PATH
fi
```

If your `.zshrc` allows something similar, this might help. If not, I'd use different files for each computer and update them individually (maybe with a script generating these files based on some shared parts?).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added an EDIT in question about the different part. It is not just as simple as `source ...` or `export...` .

Answer (score 0):

Well, pure Mercurial-centric solutions

1. Classic branching

Branch per host, started from additional "vanilla" branch (there you'll store shared code). After it in each branch you perform host-specific changes. Common changes (and **only common**) have to appear in Vanilla branch and merged to the rest

1. MQ patches

Single branch, purpose identical to Vanilla from p.1 ("changesets contain common base"). All mutable host-specific changes stored in set of mq-patch's queue (or, for fresh Mercurial, in *queues* maybe). How to organize patch-stack is fully your area of responsibility:

- You can use one queue and full set of patches for every host (name-based separation), even if some different patches are clones of another. Result: easy operations for preparing actual fileset for host, you have to apply all NAME-* patches
- Functional separation: every patch serve for single task (BOSS, ORACLE, PROXY, PROXY-CONFIG...). Result: less patches, logical combining of files from blocks, expandable for wider hosts-set without changing internal logic
- Separate queues: Each host have own queue.  Result: "foreign" patches never will be applied to host, drawback - harder (or impossible) patches exchange between queues, functional clones as in version "full set" (really it's variation of "full set" with stronger separation)

Comment: the MQ looks interesting, I would take a look and try it. see if it suits my needs. Thank you.

Comment: for approach 1, there are 4 branches in total. every time if I did changes on vanilla branch, I have to merge to the other 3. and if I want to change both common and host-specific on one machine, I should do in different branches and merge. it's a bit error-prone, isn't it? For the MQ, If I understood right, I should only qrefresh each queue, never qfinish and push right? So the host-specific stuff are always stored in my working copy. or I have a wrong understanding?

Comment: " if I want to change both common and host-specific on one machine, I should do in different branches and merge." Yes, you should do it this way. " it's a bit error-prone, isn't it?" - at least not for me: I **use** "branch-per-task" all time. " For the MQ, If I understood right, I should only qrefresh each queue, never qfinish and push right?" - yes, expecpt rare cases, when some configuration promoted to *shared common* (this way LibreOffice from experiment on single host became common replacement of OpenOffice in my net)