# Version control of dotfiles with machine-specific changesets

Tags: git, bash, git-config, dotfiles

I store dotfiles in a git repo, however I do have different set of local changes for `.gitconfig` (which is under version control) - it may be different environment (autocrlf true) or different username.

Right now every time I checkout the repo I go for:

```
git stash save && git pull && git stash apply
```

Which doesn't seem like a best practice to me. How should I go about having different set of local changes on different machines? What's the cleanest and the most explicit way? Or am I even addressing the wrong problem to begin with?

Comment: take a look this question (from me ealier) I did it with shell script right now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364444/partial-branch-or-partial-merge-or-other-way-to-help-me-to-sync-dotfiles

Comment: @Kent I can see how this can be applied to regular bash configs, but I don't think same approach can be applied for `.gitconfig`...

Comment: Is it possible to use a global `~/.gitconfig` file for common settings and the repository local config for user specific settings?

Comment: @AndrewMyers I am looking for machine-specific changes to version controlled `~/.gitconfig`, where `~` is a dotfiles repository. I don't think that changing settings for every local repo on a machine is very scalable

Comment: @rosipov That's what I was wondering.  I have some things that are constant across most of my repositories and occasionally overridden by a repository config file.  It sounds like that won't work for you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to split out host-specific settings into a non-tracked file.
the `include`-statement is available in git>=1.7.10.

something like following could do the trick:

```
 [include]
 path = ~/.gitconfig.local
```

i guess, what would be really nifty, would be something like:

```
 [include]
 path = ~/.gitconfig.${HOSTNAME}.local
```

and then track both `.gitconfig.foo.local` and `.gitconfig.bar.local` in the repository, but the former get's used on host `foo` and the latter on host `bar`. unfortunately variable-expansion is currently not supported.

---

alternatively you might set your GIT_CONFIG environment-variable to a system-specific value in your `.bash_profile`/`.profile`/`.bashrc`

---

finally, git uses `${prefix}/etc/gitconfig` for host-wide configuration, probably you can use this for host-wide configuration.